# Edit or Add a Section in "Links" tab in Catalog -> Products in Opencart

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I'm new to opencart and I'd really like to let's say modify or tweak a little the "Links" tab that is located in the Catalog -> Products (and then click in the Edit product action) in the  admin page, to be more specific this is the image of the tab I'm referring to: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-tWYu8QFe4NZXZDU2VUVVlndjQ/view?usp=sharing.

I want to add a new section in which I can use some checkboxes to select multiple options like in this example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-tWYu8QFe4NQTVaV1dXLS12dlk/view?usp=sharing

I'm not new to PHP and/or MVC but I'd really like some directions on this, I know that I have to modify the product_form.tpl for the admin view and also add something in the model and controller. I think I can use the store section as a guide, also I have a question in this part: to create the section that I want, do I have to create tables in the DB? or can I do something else? I hope I've been clear with this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is default feature if you don't know, 
First Create List of Options you want

```
Admin>Catalog>option>add option
//add options here

Admin>Catalog>product>edit product
//in Option tab you can assign options here
```

Comment: I tried what you said and it's not what I'm looking for, nevertheless thanks for your answer.
It allows me to add the options that I want but, I can't place them where I need them.